# How to omit childs while selecting elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page like this

```
     <ul id="carousel_ul" style="left: -130px;" >

         <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Test 2</a>

             <div class="subnav">
                 <ul class="left">
                     <li><h2>JavaScript</h2></li>
                     <li><a href="#" title="JS Article 1">JS Article 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" title="JS Article 2">JS Article 2</a></li>
                     <li class="last"><a href="#" title="JS Article 3">JS Article 3</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 <ul class="right">
                     <li><h2>jQuery</h2></li>
                     <li><a href="#" title="jQuery Article 1">jQuery Article 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" title="jQuery Article 2">jQuery Article 2</a></li>
                     <li class="last"><a href="#" title="jQuery Article 3">jQuery Article 3</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>

         </li>

         <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Test 5</a>

             <ul class="subnav">
                 <li class="first"><a href="#" title="The first demo">The first demo</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" title="Another demo">Another demo</a></li>
                 <li class="last"><a href="#" title="The third demo">The third demo</a></li>
             </ul>

         </li>

         <li><a href="#">Test 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 7</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 8</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 9</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 10</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 11</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test 12</a></li>

     </ul>

 </div> <!--end of div id="carousel_inner"  -->
```

I am selecting the elements like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));
    ....

}); //end of $(document).ready(fn)
```

When **carousel_ul li** makes li array then it contain all the li and the children of li as well. Like first li become `<li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>, <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>, <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>` and so on. But when second li comes then it contain all the childrens as well. Like **Test2 li** contain **a, div, ul class=left, li, ul class=right, li**. I want that if my li has submenus like **test2 li** and **test5 li**. It will only select it like

```
 <li>
     <a href="#">Test 2</a>
 </li>

 <li>
     <a href="#">Test 5</a>
 </li>
```

I mean to say although **li test2** and **li test5** has submenus in it, but when line **$('#carousel_ul li:first')** run, then it will treat **li test2** and **li test5** like the **li test1** or **li test3**. Like if i select the **li test2** , then i should get something like this

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">Test 5</a>
</li>
```

instead of

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>

    <div class="subnav">
        <ul class="left">
            <li><h2>JavaScript</h2></li>
            ....
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><h2>jQuery</h2></li>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>

</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">Test 5</a>

    <ul class="subnav">
        <li class="first"><a href="#" title="The first demo">The first demo</a></li>
        ...      
    </ul>

</li>
```

How can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: do you know about the nextUnitl? might apply here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone the items you want and then remove the child from the clones.

Comment: @ mindandmedia sorry i don't know about nextUntil, but i check the API for this.You mean first i make a clone of ul and then remove the elemnts from the clone and then use that clone? Thanks

Comment: I meant clone the result from the query, where you have the li you want but with unwanted child beside the <a href="#"></a>. then you can just remove these unwanted tags.